# Errors with Karma and Jasmine caused by cross-domain AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, xss, jasmine, karma-runner

I am setting up tests that use Jasmine and Karma to test my JavaScript.  Karma runs in Node.js and starts a Chrome browser.

I keep getting and error "Chrome 28.0 (Windows) ERROR Script error. at :0"  Upon tracing through things I realized that some of the objects I create in my code make AJAX cross-domain AJAX calls and when they do that my Karma tests crash.

I do not need these AJAX calls to succeed for my tests to succeed, however I would like them to not crash my Karma tests.

I am open to solve this issue in a wide variety of ways.  Can I change my Karma/Chrome settings so the AJAX will not fail catastrophically?  Can I override XMLHttpRequest so either the offending requests aren't made or no requests are made?

Notes:
The test does not fail in the debug window even though that it is also making cross domain AJAX requests.

I have am using a testing library that overrides jQuery's AJAX.  However, I have another library that is still making AJAX requests.

Comment: And can't you just override the ajax methods of the other library?

Comment: I am using AMD and it would be difficult to set up, as far as I know.

Answer (score 6):

I was having a similar issue with CORS and AJAX, then I followed jhamm suggestion. Then, I got "ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start chrome_without_security Can not find the binary chrome_without_security".

Since my issue was with CORS, I found out [here](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher/issues/154) that I should add the new browser type to the browsers list on karma.conf.js.

I added it like this:

```
browsers: ['Chrome_without_security'],
customLaunchers:{
    Chrome_without_security:{
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: ['--disable-web-security']
    }
}
```

After that, and since I only have this one browser, I don't have to use

```
karma start --browsers Chrome_without_security
```

I can just type

```
karma start
```

And it will call for the HeadlessChrome without security, meaning it won't find any problems with CORS.

Answer (score 2):

If it really is a CORS issue, you can disable the cross-domain by starting karma like this:

```
karma start --browsers chrome_without_security
```

Chrome has the ability to be started with the security disabled

```
open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security
```

And the Karma team just takes advantage of it.

Comment: I get "ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start chrome_without_security Can not find the binary chrome_without_security".  I see stuff on the web that suggests I should do Chrome_without_security, but that just leads to "Can not find the binary Chrome_without_security".